# Context Propagation in Micronaut

Tags: micronaut

I'm currently migrating an application which was originally written in the [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/) to [Micronaut](https://micronaut.io/). The application relies on context propagation to propagate transactional context. In Quarkus, this was easily achievable using the provided [context propagation extension](https://quarkus.io/guides/context-propagation).
Unfortunately there seems to be no similar extension/feature in Micronaut (at least I couldn't find any).

If there isn't any alternative, how can I add the context propagation feature to my application in Micronaut?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general synchronous transactions can't be propagated across different threads so I am not sure how it helps to propagate them in your case.

Micronaut Data R2DBC supports non-blocking transactions and transactional context propagation for reactive flows if that is what you are after https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-r2dbc/1.0.x/guide/#transactionManagement

Comment: I wasn't exactly using a reactive transaction. My use case was as follows: scheduled method starts a transaction (with timeout) -> method invokes a long running action in a new thread and waits for the result (or timeout) -> if action times out fail gracefully, otherwise persist changes to db. Note the parallel operation may perform db operations as well and i wanted them to take place within the context of the callers transaction. Quarkus uses https://github.com/eclipse/microprofile-context-propagation to propagate transaction context via ManagedExecutor.

Comment: In the end, i didn't actually need it. I was only performing read operations within the parallel operation and needed transactions specifically to load lazy associations. But instead i decided to go with adding @Transactional(REQUIRED) to my repositories and loading associations eagerly with join fetches.